# Python -- nondimensionalize

Tags: python, user-defined-functions

I'm writing a python module to allow me to make unit-based calculations, and I'm trying to implement unit-sensitive integration of functions. My idea is basically to write a wrapper for scipy.integrate -- take the function and arguments given, including the limits of integration, nondimensionalize them all, pass to scipy.integrate.quad or some such thing, get the answer, and then multiply by the correct units at the end.

To accomplish this, I'm trying to figure out how to nondimensionalize an arbitrary function. I've implemented units so that if you divide two quantities with the same units, it returns an ordinary number, so my first thought was to just do this:

```
def nonDimensionalize(func, *args):
    val = func(*args)
    dimensions = val / val.value
    return lambda args : (func(args) / dimensions)
```

This works like a charm to nondimensionalize the function's output, but I'm having a harder time with the input. What I really need is to return a function that takes in ordinary numbers, multiplies them by the correct SI dimensions (which I can figure out how to do), gets the output, divides it by the correct SI dimensions, and returns that value as an ordinary number. Then I can pass said function to scipy.integrate (or scipy.fslove, etc.). I tried the following:

```
def nonDimensionalize(func, *args):
    argDims = []
    for arg in args:
        aDim = arg / arg.value
        argDims.append(aDim)
    nDargs = []
    index = 0
    for arg in args:
        nDargs.append(arg / argDims[index])
        index += 1
    val = func(*args)
    dimensions = val / val.value
    return lambda args : (func(args) / dimensions)
```

but it doesn't work; it has exactly the same effect as my four-line function above. I'm not sure how to proceed at this point. Help?

Comment: You might check out the `quantities` module. It is designed to do arithmetic with physical measurements while taking into account the units involved. http://pythonhosted.org//quantities/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I really need is to return a function that takes in ordinary numbers, multiplies them by the correct SI dimensions (which I can figure out how to do), gets the output, divides it by the correct SI dimensions, and returns that value as an ordinary number.

I'm not sure I understand exactly how you dimensionalize/non-dimensionalize values, so just modify the corresponding functions as necessary, but you could do it like this:

```
def dimensionalizeValue(nonDimValue, dimensions):
    return nonDimValue * dimensions

def nonDimensionalizeValue(dimValue):
    dimensions = dimValue / dimValue.value
    return dimValue / dimensions

def nonDimensionalizeFunction(function):
    def wrapper(*nonDimArgs):
        # Figure out the correct dimensions.
        dimensions = None
        # Transform/dimensionalize the arguments.
        dimArgs = [dimensionalizeValue(arg, dimensions) for arg in nonDimArgs]
        # Get output using dimensionalized arguments.
        dimVal = function(*dimArgs)
        # Non-dimensionalize the output.
        nonDimVal = nonDimensionalizeValue(dimVal)
        return nonDimVal
    return wrapper
```